# Spring Cloud FeignClient decoding application/hal+json Resource<Object> return type

Tags: spring-data-rest, spring-cloud, spring-hateoas

I'm developing a REST API using Spring Cloud, Spring Data JPA, Spring Data Rest and Spring Boot. The server implementation generates the various data items correctly, according to the HAL spec and so forth. It generates the HAL+JSON as follows:

```
{
  "lastModifiedBy" : "unknown",
  "lastModifiedOn" : "2015-06-04T12:19:45.249688",
  "id" : 2,
  "name" : "Item 2",
  "description" : null,
  "_links" : {
    "self" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:8080/pltm/accounts/2"
    },
    "customers" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:8080/pltm/accounts/2/customers"
    },
    "users" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:8080/pltm/accounts/2/users"
    },
    "groups" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:8080/pltm/accounts/2/groups"
    }
  }
}
```

Now I'm trying to implement the client implementation, using the FeignClient Spring Cloud library. I've defined my client interface as follows.

```
@FeignClient("serviceId")
@RequestMapping(value = "/api", consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public interface PltmClient
{
  // Account Requests
  @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "/accounts")
  PagedResources<Resource<Account>> getAccounts();

  @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "/accounts/{id}")
  Resource<Account> getAccountAsResource(@PathVariable("id") Long id);

  @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "/accounts/{id}")
  Account getAccount(@PathVariable("id") Long id);
}
```

When I call the `getAccout()` method, I get back my domain object `Account` with the details from the JSON document. That object is a simple POJO. All of the fields are filled in properly.

```
public class Account
{
   private Long id;
   private String name;
   private String description;

   /** Setters/Getters left out for brevity **/
 }
```

But when I call the `getAccountAsResource()`, it works and I get back a `Resource` object that has the data. However, the call to `Resource.getContent()` returns an `Account` object that is not completely filled out. In this case, the `Account.getId()` is NULL, which is causing problems.

Any ideas why this is happening? One idea I had is that the `Resource` class defines a `getId()` method, and that is somehow confusing the Jackson ObjectMapper.

The larger question is if this whole method is viable or is there a better way? Obviously, I could just use the plain POJO as my return type, but that looses the HAL information on the client side.

Has anyone successfully implemented a Java-based client implementation for Spring Data REST server endpoints?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Account` not having an id is a feature of spring-data-rest.  You need to enable populating of the id on the server side.

I also add a different method to return the id (in Account)

```
@JsonProperty("accountId")
public String getId() {
    return id;
}
```

Enable id

```
@Configuration
public class MyConfig extends RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration {

    @Override
    protected void configureRepositoryRestConfiguration( RepositoryRestConfiguration config) {
        config.exposeIdsFor(Account.class);
    }
}
```

I have used it here: https://github.com/spencergibb/myfeed, though I believe where I use resources, I'm using `RestTemplate`.

Comment: I did enable the sending of the id field on the server side. That is what the "id" field in the JSON above is coming from. So I see the data leaving the server in the JSON stream. The issue is on the client side, when trying to have the JSON mapped to a ````Resource<Account>````, something is getting confused and not mapping the id. If I just make the return type ````Account````, then I do see the id being populated.

Comment: I worked around it by having another property in the json that isn't id (ie accountId above).

Comment: Ok, I understand what you mean now. I was able to add another property to the server-produced JSON for the embedded object, ````Account```` in this case, and using the ````@JsonProperty````` mappings, have that mapped to the ````id```` attributes of the object. Its a little annoying I have to send the additional value in the JSON, as it makes the API a little more confusing. Would this be considered a bug of the JSON object mapping logic?